# TF205020 and TF30063 cannot connect to server errors when opening Visual Studio 2017

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I'm getting this error in the output window every time I open Visual Studio 2017 (v. 15.3.2):

[image: TF205020 error in the output window]

And then when I click on Team Explorer I get this popup error:

[image: TFS30063 error in popup window]

After closing that pop-up, I can still connect normally to the TFS server and my projects through "Manage Connections" and then continue my work normally, but the next time I open up Visual Studio I'll get these errors again.

**Things I've noticed:**

- In the TF205020 error message, "Could not connect to server '{url}'",
  the URL is incorrect. It has an additional directory after the
  domain e.g. *mycompany.visualstudio.com\mycompany*. I think it should just be *mycompany.visualstudio.com*. I haven't been able to find where this is coming from.
- If I hit Ctrl+Alt+R to open up a browser inside of VS, it tries to
  connect to *https: //msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/* which is an invalid
  link and navigation to the page fails. Not sure if this is related.

**Things I've tried:**

- Googling and searching Stack Overflow for similar issues.
- Re-entering my VS account credentials, removing my account entirely
  and re-adding it. No luck.
- Using Visual Studio 2015. These errors **do not** occur when using
  2015, they only occur in 2017.
- Deleting \Users{User}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team
  Foundation\7.0\Cache and this actually stops the errors coming up,
  but only once. Once the cache is reloaded, the errors come back.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue in VS 2017 15.3, please see the [feedback here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/93366/tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-visualstu.html).

According to **Abraham's** comment "**The bugfix hasn't been prepared for release yet.**"